# Creating a Gerrit review from an existing commit on a remote branch

Tags: gerrit

I've already created a remote branch and pushed to it some commits. How can I create a gerrit review on commits already existing on the remote branch?

One workaround is to add an empty space in the commit message, thus changing the SHA-1 and then performing `git review`. I was wondering if there's a possible solution (perhaps directly in the gerrit web ui?) without modifying the commits.

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities:

- Merge this already existing branch in another branch creating a change (review) for this (pushing the merge commit to /refs/for/BRANCH).
- Revert these commits and after that push them to review again.